# How to show absolute positioned div when hover to card using Tailwind?

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, css-position

I have Next.js app with Tailwind. I want to show some additional information when hover to product card, inspired from wildberries.ru. It show some information above of other products. I tried using group, group:hover, but background for absolute positioned div is not works. How to do that like in below image?

[[image: wildberries product1]

Product component:

```
const Product = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className='group rounded-md space-y-1 hover:bg-white hover:shadow-lg'>
      <div className='relative'>
        {/*Image*/}
        </div>

      <div className='flex flex-col'>
        {/*Price, name, rating*/}
        </div>

      <div className='z-10 hidden absolute group-hover:flex'>
        {/*Must be shown when hover, Add to cart button and sizes*/}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Product;
```

Comment: What version of tailwind are you using? is it v2 or v3?

Comment: Tailwind version v3

Answer (score 2):

> but background for absolute positioned div is not works

It seems like you don't have a background specified for the absolute-positioned `<div>` at all! Consider applying one to it:

```html
<div className='z-10 hidden absolute bg-white group-hover:flex'>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="grid grid-cols-2">
  <div class='group rounded-md space-y-1 hover:bg-white hover:shadow-lg'>
    <div class='relative'>
      {/*Image*/}
    </div>

    <div class='flex flex-col'>
      {/*Price, name, rating*/}
    </div>

    <div class='z-10 hidden absolute bg-white group-hover:flex'>
      {/*Must be shown when hover, Add to cart button and sizes*/}
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='group rounded-md space-y-1 hover:bg-white hover:shadow-lg'>
    <div class='relative'>
      {/*Image*/}
    </div>

    <div class='flex flex-col'>
      {/*Price, name, rating*/}
    </div>

    <div class='z-10 hidden absolute bg-white group-hover:flex'>
      {/*Must be shown when hover, Add to cart button and sizes*/}
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class='group rounded-md space-y-1 hover:bg-white hover:shadow-lg'>
    <div class='relative'>
      {/*Image*/}
    </div>

    <div class='flex flex-col'>
      {/*Price, name, rating*/}
    </div>

    <div class='z-10 hidden absolute bg-white group-hover:flex'>
      {/*Must be shown when hover, Add to cart button and sizes*/}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='group rounded-md space-y-1 hover:bg-white hover:shadow-lg'>
    <div class='relative'>
      {/*Image*/}
    </div>

    <div class='flex flex-col'>
      {/*Price, name, rating*/}
    </div>

    <div class='z-10 hidden absolute bg-white group-hover:flex'>
      {/*Must be shown when hover, Add to cart button and sizes*/}
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: For image I used Next Image component. Bottom button stays behind Image component